# Android TV looks incredibly zoomed in compared to apple TV

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tvos, android-tv

I have an existing app in react native, and am trying to have it work for android tv and apple tv as well. It looks fine on apple tv, but on android tv it looks very zoomed in. Is there something I need to add to the AndroidManifest file, or can I change the pixel ratio in some way? I cannot find any information about this anywhere, so I am wondering if someone here has some experience working with react native and android tv.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.